# Telerik Report - how to hide ext column

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am working on Telerik Reporting and I need to hide/show Extension column base on the users input. Can I do this using a filter or  report parameter?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table column is just a virtual grouping instance of all the report items in the cells of that column (textboxes, panels, etc.). Therefore you can just add a [ConditionalFormatting](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/styling-conditional-formatting) rules to the textboxes in that column, setting their visibility according to a report parameter value.